# What I need add to application for supporting work profile

Tags: android, android-work-profile

Hello I want develop application that will be installed on managed profile. Scenario when user input work account and system propose install apps.

Should I add anything to my apps for starting support this?

Comment: Are you asking about how to write the management app (these days you really don't, you'd likely use Android Enterprise)?  Or are you asking if anything needs to be special in the apps you install (in which case no).

Comment: @GabeSechan I think it's second case